# Why does net.exe start <servicename> report a failure when the service starts?

Tags: java, windows, service, puppet

I have a Java application that uses the Apache Daemon service installer to register it as a Windows service.  I am using Puppet to run an exec{} block to register the service, which works, and then chains a service{} block to start the service.  Puppet uses "net.exe start" to run the service, but that command reports an error, even though the service starts correctly.

The output from running the command in a powershell shell is:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\modules> net start myservice
The myservice_descriptive_name service is starting.....
The myservice_descriptive_name service could not be started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3523.
```

As I refresh the Windows service panel while this command is running, I see the state change from:

> blank field -> starting -> started

Is this a problem caused by the apache wrapper, which is starting a jvm in a separate shell or some other side effect?  And, more importantly, can I get around this problem in Puppet while still using the service{} block?  Is it possible to substitute sc.exe, which does not suffer the same problem, short of using an exec{} block?

Comment: What does `sc query` say about the state of the service immediately after `net start` has generated that error message?

Comment: SERVICE_NAME: myservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 2284
        FLAGS              :
PS C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\modules> echo $?
True

Comment: OK, so the service really hasn't started yet when `net.exe` gives up.  Does it *ever* start?  That is, does `sc query` ever say `RUNNING` rather than `START_PENDING` ?

Comment: The service starts every time and sc.exe reports it correctly.

Comment: OK, so it hasn't started when net.exe gives up (after a minute, according to your comment below) but does start later on?  How much later?  In another comment you say the service starts within 5 seconds, so I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, no.  My comment was that my service takes less than 5 seconds to start, while research for net.exe indicates it times out after 1 minute.

Comment: In your environment, how long does `net start` wait before producing the error message posted?

Comment: Ah.  That's the wait hint (0x7D0 = 2000 milliseconds).  And the checkpoint is 0 so it isn't being incremented; net.exe must actually respect the checkpoint/wait hint system.  (I didn't know that!)  Unfortunately, it doesn't look as if procrun provides any method to configure the wait hint, or at least it isn't mentioned in the instructions.  You could work around it by "starting" immediately, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the questions in order:

- The `net start` command reports failure because the service appears to have hung.
- Yes, the problem is caused by the Apache wrapper.

Specifically, the wrapper is telling Windows that it will reach the first checkpoint within two seconds.  Since there does not appear to be any way for the Java code to implement a checkpoint, or to change the wait hint, this means that the service must start within two seconds to be compliant with the Windows service specification.

(In principle, Windows is entitled to terminate your service at this point.  So far as I know, no current versions of Windows do so, though they may log error messages.)

- Short of modifying Puppet or (preferably) the Apache wrapper, the only obvious workaround is to ensure that your service "starts" immediately, rather than waiting for initialization to complete.

This is less than ideal, since it means that the service can't provide feedback to Puppet if it really does fail to initialize, but no worse than your suggestion of using `sc start` instead of `net start`.

Answer (score 1):

JPBlanc's answer explains why the net.exe times out waiting on the service to start, even though it does end up starting. You can definitely try swapping out `net.exe` calls for `sc.exe` (Service Control) instead.

I've created a ticket to address this - https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5475

If you find that it doesn't also timeout while waiting, please comment and/or file a pull request containing the change. At any rate, using something better than `net.exe` would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for opening the ticket.  I linked the ticket I opened to it, as yours better encapsulates the merits of changing the behaviour.

Comment: By the way, starting this service takes less than 5 seconds, which is reasonable for a process to start.  The service runner is a well aged apache project, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/, which has served me for years.  My own application that is wrapped by this service runner is standalone, so no DB dependencies or the like.  Basically, no good reason for net.exe to throw an error.  Research indicates a one minute timeout for net.exe.

Comment: I believe that analysis is incorrect; there is nothing wrong with net.exe.  The most likely problem is that the service itself is not correctly reporting its status back to Windows.  According to the OP, `sc` also shows that the service hasn't started yet.

Comment: Using `sc start` instead of `net start` might be an OK workaround.  Just be aware that it doesn't check whether the service actually starts successfully or not.

Comment: Yeah Harry we were talking about that sc may be non-blocking. We may go down to native Windows calls through FFI as a better solution.

Comment: [Replacing my earlier comment.]  It looks like the problem is that the service is telling Windows it should only take 2 seconds to start up (via the wait hint / checkpoint system) and net.exe is respecting that.  So yes, if you use native calls you could work around the problem by having minimum/maximum timeout periods, or by ignoring the checkpoint and wait hint altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that the service takes too much time to start and does not communicate correctly with the starter.

When you write a service that initiate communications or DB connections you have to communicate with the Service Control Manager (SCM) to give the information that you are starting. Doing this kind of "I'am still starting message" the SCM can wait as mus time as you need to start. But much service writer or or tools to encapsulate exe files as services ignore that, so the SCM return "service could not be started". In Win32 this is handled by [SetServiceStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241(v=vs.85).aspx) function, you will have much details there.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the whole question, which is whether it's possible to substitute sc.exe for net.exe in puppet's service{} implementation.  It also doesn't really answer the reason why net.exe reports an error for a state condition that is managed by Windows.  That is, if Windows changes a service's state between stopped -> starting -> started, then it shouldn't throw an error message saying the service cannot be started, until the state change cycle has completed. I regard this as a bug, regardless of the cause.

Comment: I also see this as a bug. See my answer regarding next steps. Thanks for asking about it!